# Call REST Api from within REST Api (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, rest

This might be a silly question but I'm quite new to Node/REST and could not find a answer.

Say there is a Request A that asks for Object A ('../student/:studentId').
And there is another Request B that asks for Object B ('.../lecture/:lectureid'). Now Object B will contain some information about the lecture but also the students that attend the lecture.

Now I can think of three possbile ways to assemble Object B:

1.: Call Request A several times from within the processing of Resquest B

2.: Copy and paste the code from the processing of Request A

3.: Create an object that accesses the database and attach it to all request queries:

```
    var dbAccessObject = require('./dbAccess');

    app.use(function (req,res,next){
      req.dbAccessObject = dbAccessObject;
      next();
    )};
```

Which option would you choose? Or is there another, better way?

Comment: 3rd one, because calling ur own server from your own server is not so efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to forward requests to yourself. You can handle it within your own code by structuring it nicely. Let's say you have two API routes:

```
/a: runA();
/b: runB();
```

And you would like /c to return the result of both /a and /b as if two calls were made. If you have broken your logic down to `runA()` and `runB()` as above, then /c becomes `runC()`:

```
return {
  a: runA(),
  b: runB()
}
```

This is simple when writing synchronous code, but asynchronous code is a bit more difficult because `runB()` could return before `runA()`; you need to know when they are both finished. I recommend using the `async` library for this *as a quick win*: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2265406&seqNum=2

Comment: And the implementation should be as in option 3? Or are there other ways to make the methods available in different files? Ah and thank you for the additional information about the async lib

Comment: Yeah. "Copy and paste the code" is rarely a good idea. I made an example of using async earlier today: https://tonicdev.com/jadaradix/async